# Next js 13 routing Error: Invariant: attempted to hard navigate to the same URL Fix

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, next.js13

I am using Next.js 13, and when I try to navigate to a page which is not present, I get the following error:

Error: Invariant: attempted to hard navigate to the same URL.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

it shoud redirect to 404 without anyt erroe it is redirecting to 404 but i am also getting a 404 error